# If $X$ is an infinite set, then $X$ with the discrete topology is not compact

Tags: general-topology

I am new to compact sets, and I had some hard time trying to solve this:

Let $X$ be an infinite set; $T$ the discrete topology on $X$ .Prove that $(X,T)$ is not compact.

I know that I may consider the open cover $\{\{x\},x \in X\}$ and prove that it doesn't have a finite subcover,but I don't know how to write it exactly.

Moreover, I seriously can't understant why $X$ itself cannot be considered as a finite subcover?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: $\{ \{ x \} : x \in X\}$ can't be a finite subcover because $X$ is infinite.

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/ Also, $X\notin\{\{x\}:x\in X\}$.

Comment: Each singleton set is open.  You would have to find a finite number of them whose union is $X$ -- clearly impossible.  $\{X\}$ is not a subcover because $X$ is not one of the sets in the original cover.

Comment: Thank you very much.I find it more clear now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed take the cover $\mathcal{U}=\{\{x\}: x \in X\}$. This is clearly a cover of $X$ as every $p \in X$ is in $\{p\} \in \mathcal{U}$ and in fact *only* in that set.

It's an open cover because the topology is discrete and so *all* subsets of $X$ are open.

A finite subcover is a finite subset of $\mathcal{U}$ (so these are all singleton sets too) that together cover $X$ too. But this cannot exist: if $\mathcal{F}$ is a finite subset of $\mathcal{U}$ then it consists of finitely many singletons $\{x_1\},\{x_2\},\ldots, \{x_N\}$ for some finite $N$. But $X$ has infinitely many points so there are infinitely many $x \notin \{x_1,\ldots,x_N\}$, say $p$ is one of those. Then $p$ is in none of the sets of $\mathcal{F}$, and so this finite subset of $\mathcal{U}$ is not a cover of $X$.

Hence $\mathcal{U}$ has no finite subcover. In fact, if you think about it, we cannot remove a single element $\{p\}$ from $\mathcal{U}$ or $p$ would no longer be covered at all; every point is only covered once... The set $X$ is not even an element of $\mathcal{U}$ so does not qualify as a possible subcover. A subcover is a selection of open sets from the cover, and $X$ is not one of them, there are just singletons.

To think about: the open cover of all doubletons $\{x,y\}, x \neq y$ would also have worked: a finite subset (say of size $N$) of that cover can only cover $2N$ points at most and so must also miss points of $X$, etc. In this cover every point is covered infinitely many times, and still we cannot reduce it to a finite subcover.

To show non-compactness we only have to find **one** cover without a finite subcover, because compactness is the strong statement that **every** open cover of $X$ must have a finite subcover. So one counterexample suffices to kill it.